# Searching for Old YouTube Videos

Tags: search, youtube

I'm trying to find all of the YouTube videos created by IGN's channel during the month of February 2014.  IGN currently has 118,000+ videos uploaded, so going back through all of them is not possible.  I previously used the following Google search string and a custom date range to find them:

site:youtube.com ignentertainment

This doesn't work anymore for some reason.  I'd be much obliged if anyone has any ideas of how to do this.  I have no idea what an API is, but if there's a VERY simple way of using that to do what I want that can be explained briefly, I'm willing to go that route.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google to limit the period that it fetches search hits from.

Start by searching using "site:youtube.com ignentertainment" or simply "ignentertainment" and then click on the tools button, you now got a new bar between your search bar and the results that can limit time among other things.
Open the time related options and choose to input a specified period and your all done.

Edit: oh and the command site:youtube.com ignentertainment sure worked for me.